# Proxy in Python

Tags: python, proxy, socks

I have a SOCKS 5 proxy that has a host, username and password.
I want to use this proxy in the Python program and connect to the proxy, and from now on the program will send Internet requests using the IP proxy and download the files using the proxy.
Similar to Telegram, which uses the SOCKS proxy connection.

Answer (score 1):

`requests` library supports SOCKS .

To specify an authenticated proxy, just use:

```
import requests
proxies = {'https':'socks5://username:password@proxy_ip:proxy_port'}

r = requests.get("http://www.example.com/", proxies=proxies)
```

---

***NOTE:*** `pip install "requests[socks]` needed

Comment: I want the whole program to use a proxy. I use mpv to play music. I also want to play the filtered

Comment: @a-m-h-t well then write a question that complies with the SO standards. See [ask] and [mcve]. I am sure the community will help but SO is not a free coding service.